# Java 7 and -XX:TraceDeoptimization

Tags: java, optimization, java-7, jvm-hotspot

I'm trying to debug Java deoptimization, but I can't get `-XX:+TraceDeoptimization` to work. Do you know if it was disabled in OpenJDK 7, or maybe is not enabled in my version (7u9-2.3.4-0ubuntu1.12.04.1), or if there is some magic `-XX:+unlockSomething` that I need to call?

No matter what I try, I always get the error message

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

without any further details when I add this parameter. Even a plain `java -XX:+TraceDeoptimization` prints this message. It doesn't say it does not recognize the option, either. However, as `PrintCompilation` reveals, I'm seeing a "made not entrant" messages, which apparently indicate a deoptimization, and I'd like to debug why this is happening, as I'm seeing an odd performance drop with supposedly improved code.

## Solution:

The default builds indeed *do not include* this functionality. You need a **debug build**. You can [find some with Google on jdk7.java.net](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3ajdk7.java.net%20%22debug%20builds%22).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **default builds** indeed **do not include this functionality**.

You need a **debug build**. You can [find some with Google on jdk7.java.net](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:jdk7.java.net%20%22debug%20builds%22).

Answer (score 0):

All flag options require a `+` or `-` to enable or disable them. In your case the option would be `-XX:+TraceDeoptimization` To turn it off (which is the default) you can write `-XX:-TraceDeoptimization`

Comment: That actually is what I tried. Sorry for the copy & paste above. It doesn't work here.

Comment: On a side note, `-XX:-TraceDeoptimization` causes the same error.

Comment: It might be disabled in that version. I would try the Oracle Hotspot Java 7.

Comment: Oracle Java 7 says: `Unrecognized VM option 'TraceDeoptimization'`. Which at least is an error message, although it doesn't help me debugging this performance regression... any idea which version of Java actually supports this kind of debugging?

Comment: I know they do a "debug" release with mreo options, but you may have to build one yourself as they don't do it very often.

Comment: With Google I found a JDK7 debug build on java.net, and this one indeed includes the option. Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to build this version yourself but I don't know how.

Answer (score -1):

This option is available only in the debug version of the VM. (at least that is what my idk 1.8u92 is telling me.